# Nested Excel.Run() throws exception

Tags: office-js

I have an app in the Store which works in 2016, Online and Mac. However, today Excel Online stopped working while 2016 and Mac are fine. Hard to track down as calls to Excel.Run() just throw "General Exception" but it seems to be when I call nested Excel.Run(). So like

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
  var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets.load("name");
  return ctx.sync()
     .then(function () {
     ...
     anotherfunction()
```

and in anotherfunction() it calls Excel.run() again but then throws an exception.

** added **
if I call anotherfunction() outside of the first Excel.run() then it works.

Again, the code all worked a few days ago and still works on 2016 and Mac, but not in Excel Online. Any chance Excel Online was updated cause it seems weird and hard to debug. I'm using Office 365 at office.com.

Sorry, spent all afternoon looking at this and have run out of ideas.

Jon

*** added complete snippet below ***

```
(function () {

    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded.
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {

        $(document).ready(function () {
        })
    }

})();

function allSheetsClick() {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var worksheets = ctx.workbook.worksheets.load("name");
        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.items.length; i++) {
                    getSheetRange(worksheets.items[i].name);
                }
            });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("ERROR-" + error)
    });
}

function oneSheetClick() {
    getSheetRange("Sheet1");
}

function getSheetRange(sheetname) {

    var myRange = "$A$1:$Z$100";

    var bindingid = "MyBinding" + sheetname;
    var sheetrange = sheetname + "!" + myRange;
    // add binding
    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(sheetrange, "matrix", { id: bindingid }, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            console.log("Binding added.");
        } else {
            console.log("ERROR addBinding() - " + error);
        }
    });

    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var cells = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetname).getRange(myRange).load(["values", "formulasR1C1"]);
        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Got range. # rows - " + cells.values.length);
            });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("ERROR getRange() - " + error)
    });
}
```

The problem turns out to be if I add a binding this causes an exception to be thrown in the later Excel.Run(). So in Excel Online it hits the line "console.log("ERROR getRange() - " + error)". If I comment out the binding add then it all works.

Is there a better way to structure this so I don't have to call Excel.Run() twice? But notice the second one is in a function which sometimes gets called directly.

Again, this works in Excel 2016 but started to fail in Excel Online recently (like a few days ago). Let me if you need anything else I have sample site if you need to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I can pass this on to the Excel Online team, but it would help to have a complete snippet.

That being said, doing nested `Excel.run`-s is inherently very dangerous, and can lead to a bunch of timing issues.  It also short-changes the benefits that you'd get with true batching.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish, that couldn't be part of a single `Excel.run`?

Comment: Have put a complete snippet in the original message. allSheetsClick() and oneSheetClick() are just onClick events to a html button, but allSheetsClick calls Excel.run() twice while oneSheetClick only once. allSheetsClick() always fails. oneSheetClicks() seems to work the first time, but then fails the rest of the time. Thought it might be because the binding already exists but it seems to add okay and in my bigger program I handle this properly. So it might have nothing to do with nested Excel.run() but something with binding. If can let me know as my app is totally broken now. thx

Comment: Your call to `getSheetRange(worksheets.items[i].name)` is firing asynchronously which is causing you to have multiple Excel.run calls happening at once. In other words, if you have 3 items in the array if will fire off getSheetRange 3 times at once. You need to wait for the first call to getSheetRange to return before calling a 2nd, 3rd, etc. time.

Comment: If I remove the loop so it only calls getSheetRange() once it still get the error. Similarly if I call oneSheetClick() I get the error.

Comment: Sorry. It seems the add binding and getRange was also conflicting. Ok wasn't aware the async calls could conflict with each other. So how can you make function calls await? ie. up in the top for loop level

Comment: Thinking more about this, just because Excel.run is async and you have more than 2 jobs in the queue doesn't mean it should throw an exception. I thought the idea of Excel.run was to batch them to run later. ie. oneSheetClick() when it adds a binding and calls Excel.run(). I don't care the order they are run but it should not throw an exception. Otherwise Excel.run() isn't thread-safe. I also have code where one thread reads cells and another write cells and if it happens around the same time I get an exception. Is this something that changed recently as didn't notice this problem before.

Comment: Hi @JL8707, apologies for the delay.  Looks like there is actually a bug, now under investigation, with Excel Online having issues with multiple async calls.  So:  you should be able to (within reason, aka within ~50 requests) have multiple requests that can go on simultaneously.  We will update this thread once the issue is resolved.

Comment: For the how-to-have multiple Excel.runs together at the same time (and the current Online issue aside, as that should be resolved soon, and should resume the same behavior as desktop), probably best to ask a separate thread.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the update. Let me know when this is fixed and rolled out and I can test it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related to another bug we found and fixing it in the next week (target). It caused binding APIs to fail when run concurrently. It started to appear on March-30th and affects Excel online only. I can update this thread once fix is rolled out to production.